# mysql GUI for 19.04

Tags: mysql, 19.04

currently it seems like mysql workbench is unavailable for 19.04. Is there even any good alternatives with similar feats, or am I bound to use the mysql shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try DBeaver, its bundled separate or as eclipse extension